# PHP remove extra delimiters from .csv

Tags: php, csv, delimiter

I want to write a code to remove extra delimiters for each row for a .csv file. With another code i have already determined that the .csv file only contains rows with too many delmiters. I further know which column (after nth delimiter) has extra delimiters. I have already written most of the code, but it's not working yet. Help is very much appreciated.

My PHP skills are still basic.

```
<?php

$delimiter                      = ';';          //type delimiter
$delimiter_start_column         =23;            //column-to-be-cleaned starts after this delimiter
$exp_delimiter                  =63;            //expected delimiters per row
$total_delimiter                =substr_count($line,$delimiter);        //total delimiters in row
$delimiter_end_column           =($exp_delimiter - $delimiter_start_column) + ($total_delimiter - $exp_delimiter); //column-to-be-cleaned ends before this delimiter

function splitleft($line,$delimiter,$delimiter_start_column){
    $max = strlen($line);
    $n = 0;
    for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
        if($line[$i]==$delimiter){
            $n++;
            if($n>=$delimiter_start_column){
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    $arr[] = substr($line,0,$i);

    return $arr;
}

function splitright($line,$delimiter,$delimiter_end_column){
    $max = strlen($line);
    $n = 0;
    for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
        if($line[$i]==$delimiter){
            $n++;
            if($n>=$delimiter_end_column){
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    $arr[] = substr($line,$i,$max);

    return $arr;
}

// determine start time in microseconds for runtime calculation
$file['datestamp']      =   date("Y-m-d_H-i-s", $start);

$input['folder']        =   'input\\';
$input['file']          =   '';                     //enter filename

$output['folder']       =   'output\\';
$output['file_cleaned'] =   $file['datestamp'].'_cleaned_';


// open input file read-only
$handle['input']        =   @fopen($input['folder'].$input['file'], "r");

// initialize line, clean and dirty counters
$counter['total']       =   0;
$counter['cleaned']     =   0;

if($handle['input']) {
    // open output files. set point to end of file.
    $handle['cleaned']  =   @fopen($output['folder'].$output['file_cleaned'].$input['file'], "a");

    while(($line = fgets($handle['input'])) !== false) {
        // increment line counter
        $counter['total']++;
        $result             =   substr_count($line, $delimiter);

        if($result == $exp_delimiters AND $counter['line'] != 1 AND $line != $header) {
        // if the number of delimiters matches the expected number as represented by $exp_delimiters

            // increment clean lines counter
            $counter['cleaned']++;

            $output_file    =   $handle['cleaned'];
            }
        else {
        // else, if the number of delimiters does not match the expectation

            // remove extra delmiters from column
            $line_cleaned = splitleft + str_replace(";","",substr($line,strlen(splitleft()),(strlen($line)-strlen(splitleft())-strlen(splitright()))) + splitright());
            $output_file    =   $handle['cleaned'];
        }

        // prefix line number
        $line               =   $counter['total'].$delimiter.$line;

        // write line to correct output file
        fwrite($output_file, $line_cleaned);

        // output progress every 20.000 processed lines
        if($counter['total'] % 20000 == 0) {
            echo number_format($counter['total'], 0, ',', '.')."\r\n";
        }
    }
    if(!feof($handle['input'])){
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }

    // close all input and output files
    foreach($handle AS $close) {
        fclose($close);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Could you provide us a sample, the current returned data and the expected returned data?

Comment: Can't share sample unfortunately. But input is a .csv file with n records. Output should be exact same, however the extra delimiters should be removed.

Example of Input
ABC;DEFG;H;I;J;KLMN

Example of output
ABC;DEFG;HIJ;KLMN